# Understanding Lowenheim-Skolem theorem and its consequences

Tags: logic, model-theory

Based on my limited understanding, the precise formulation of [Lowenheim-Skolem (LS) theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) is stated as follows:

> Let $\Gamma$ be a set of sentences from a countable language $\mathcal L$. Let $\mathcal M$ be an infinite model for $\Gamma$, i.e. $|\text{dom}(\mathcal M)|\ge\aleph_0$. Then,
>
> - (Upward part) For every cardinal number $\kappa\ge|\text{dom}(\mathcal M)|$, there exists an elementary extension $\mathcal N$ of $\mathcal M$ such that $|\text{dom}(\mathcal N)|=\kappa$.
> - (Downward part) For every infinite cardinal number $\kappa<|\text{dom}(\mathcal M)|$, there exists an elementary substructure $\mathcal N$ of $\mathcal M$ such that $|\text{dom}(\mathcal N)|=\kappa$.

According to [Sets, Logic, Computation](https://slc.openlogicproject.org/slc-screen.pdf), one of the consequences of this theorem is that FOL cannot express that the size of a structure is uncountable. I don't understand what it means. What does it mean to "express" exactly? I interpreted this statement as for any infinite cardinal $\kappa>\aleph_0$ (not sure if this result holds for $\kappa=\aleph_0$), there is no set of sentences $\Gamma$ such that it satisfies $\mathcal M\models\Gamma$ iff $|\text{dom}(\mathcal M)|=\kappa$. Is that correct? For if there is such $\kappa$ and $\Gamma$, then certaintly, one direction "$\mathcal M\models\Gamma$ if $|\text{dom}(\mathcal M)|=\kappa$" holds but the other "$\mathcal M\models\Gamma$ only if $|\text{dom}(\mathcal M)|=\kappa$" is false because FOL cannot "control" the size of $\text{dom}(\mathcal M)$ according to LS theorem...?

Did I misunderstand anything?

Comment: These are not written correctly. For the upward part, it should say for every infinite cardinal with $\kappa \ge |dom(\mathcal M)|$ there is an *elementary* extension of $\mathcal M$ with cardinality $\kappa$ and the downward part should say for every *infinite* $\kappa \le |dom(\mathcal M|$ there is an elementary submodel of $\mathcal M$ with cardinality $\kappa.$ It is possible for a theory with an infinite model to have a finite model, but not necessarily so, e.g. it's impossible if the theory is complete (and no finite structure can be an *elementary* substructure of an infinite structure)

Comment: (I'm not sure why I said "infinite cardinal" in the statement of the upward theorem.. it's not wrong, but it's implied by the condition that $\mathcal M$ is infinite, which is necessary. It's crucial to stipulate $\kappa$ is infinite in the statement of the downward theorem, for reasons mentioned above.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Fixed

Comment: I think you might actually be asking about the compactness theorem when you ask about FOL "controlling" size.  The compactness theorem states that if every finite subset of $\Gamma$ has a model then so does $\Gamma$.  The upshot of this is that any statement that is inherently infinitary in nature cannot be expressed in FOL, for instance there is no FOL sentence S in the language of graphs such that M satisfies S iff M is connected.  In essence, compactness means that FOL cannot distinguish inherently infinitary properties, one of which is being uncountable.

Comment: @someone Yes, I am curious about its relationship with LS theorem. There is one consequence of the compactness theorem I learned that says FOL cannot express finiteness, i.e. there is no $\Gamma$ such that it satisfies $\mathcal M\models\Gamma$ iff $\text{dom}(\mathcal M)$ is finite. Since FOL cannot express uncountable by LS theorem, I figured that an analogous result must hold...

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I only want to learn what the textbook meant by "expressing uncountable."

Comment: I think "FOL cannot express that the size of a structure is uncountable" can/should be understood as "there is no consistent set of sentences $\Gamma$ such that the models of $\Gamma$ are all uncountable (ie have cardinality larger than $\aleph_0$)". This says much more than your fixed-$\kappa$ "iff" version - for example it follows from this that there can be no theory (in a countable language) whose models are all uncountable groups/fields/total orders/graphs/etc. Without LS, that's somewhat non-obvious!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I believe you are right. If this such $\Gamma$ existed, then the downward LS theorem implies it has some countable model, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out now. The LS theorem tells us that for any set of sentences $\Gamma$ in countable $\mathcal L$, FOL cannot "control" the cardinalities of its infinite models, i.e. it is inevitable that there are other infinite models for $\Gamma$ with cardinality $\ge\aleph_0$. So, it has two main consequences:

1. There is no consistent set of sentences $\Gamma$ in $\mathcal L$ such that *all* of its models are uncountably infinite. Otherwise, the downward LS theorem implies $\Gamma$ has a countably infinite model, which is a contradiction.
2. There is no consistent set of sentences $\Gamma$ in $\mathcal L$ such that *all* of its models are countably infinite. Otherwise, the upward LS theorem implies $\Gamma$ has an uncountably infinite model, which is a contradiction.